# JAVA ActionListener for every button

Tags: java, user-interface, calculator

im trying to make simple calculator in java GUI. I got to the point where I can clearly see that code is just ugly because of repeating functions like:

```
number0 = new JButton("0");
    number0.setBounds(130, 280, 50, 50);
    add(number0);

number0.addActionListener(new GetNumber0());

public class GetNumber0 implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String text =number0.getText();
            int num = Integer.parseInt(text);
            result=(result*10)+num; // +num if else than 0
            lResult.setText("Result: "+result);
        }
    }
```

Which I'm doing for every button, so is there a way to make this code look better? I'm hoping for something that can get a variable from each button individually and use it in only one fucntion named GetNumber().

Comment: For specific complex functionality you should use `Action`. If you just have a set of number buttons, why don't you make them all share the same `ActionListener`? You can get the source from `ActionEvent` instead of referring to `number0` explicitly.

Comment: Are all of your button going to be calling the same actionsPerformed() method, or does each button require a different method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a separate listener, and you really shouldn't. It's not useful to write `String text = number0.getText();` because you already know it's going to be `0`.

Share the `ActionListener` between the buttons.

```
public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton btn = (JButton) e.getSource();
        int num = Integer.parseInt(btn.getText());
        result=(result*10)+num;
        lResult.setText("Result: "+result);
    }
}
```